# Is there a way to save to the gallery instead of the SD card?

Tags: java, android, gallery

I have this code here.

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/dir1/dir2");
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, "GIFName_" + System.currentTimeMillis() +".gif");

try{
    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
    f.write(generateGIF(list));

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

my app basically converts images to .GIFS, and right now it saves it on the sd card, but I want to save it to gallery. Is there any way to do this easily? I know you can do it for images, but can you for .GIFS that are created?

Comment: No matter wherever you save, the gallery will anyways show it..gallery is just an app which shows all the public images of your device.

Answer (score 0):

Create folder in internal memory like this

```
File mydir = context.getDir("mydir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
    File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, "myfile"); 
    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir);
```

And than while saving file in the folder,give path to this directory.
Hope it helps!

Comment: By the way, for more info check out the link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal